# How do I store filtered markup?

Tags: 8

I am looking at porting Message to Drupal 8. It uses token to generate the message arguments which are HTML escaped. This is the current code.

```php
  foreach ($matches[1] as $delta => $token) {
    $output = \Drupal::token()->replace('[' . $token .  ']', array('message' => $this), $token_options);
    if ($output != '[' . $token . ']') {
      // Token was replaced and token sanitizes.
      $argument = $matches[0][$delta];
      $tokens[$argument] = FilteredMarkup::create($output);
    }
  }
$this->setArguments(array_merge($tokens, $arguments));
```

The message gets loaded and the message text API returns `new FormattableMarkup($output, $this->getArguments);`  for the message text.

The test is the following.

```php
$token_messages = array(
  'some text @{message:author} ' . $random_text,
  'some text %{message:author} ' . $random_text,
  'some text @{wrong:token} ' . $random_text,
);

$replaced_messages = array(
  'some text ' . Html::escape($this->user->label()) . ' ' . $random_text,
  'some text <em class="placeholder">' . Html::escape($this->user->label()) . '</em> ' . $random_text,
  'some text @{wrong:token} ' . $random_text,
);
```

I get a double escaping fail if I do not use `FilteredMarkup` on save because `Token::render()` uses the following code.

```php
$replacements[$token] = $value instanceof MarkupInterface ? $value : new HtmlEscapedText($value);
```

`$value` is a token replacement, which is probably already escaped. `FilteredMarkup` is marked `@internal`.

How could I achieve this?